# .mm file works if built on Xcode 7 but not on Xcode 8

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, xcode8, objective-c++

I'm calling a function from a compiled C library from a 3rd party developer which i cannot divulge. The problem is that function returns an error when the app is built using `Xcode 8`, but works ok when using `Xcode 7`. I'm calling the library function from a `.mm` file in my application. I know there's a possibility that this is caused by the 3rd party library, but what are the changes in the Xcode versions which might be affecting this? I have no idea where to start, and cannot paste code here.

Comment: Have you checked the environment? Are all configuration files, initialization calls etc. are really the same? Have you checked if the function is called with the same parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a workaround for this but still don't know why it behaves like that.
I found the cause of the error was the `Optimization Level`. When in XCode 8, I need to set optimization level for it to work, or else it fails.

The specific source code that fails is this:

```
char subject[256];
memset(&subject, 0x00, sizeof(subject));
strcpy(subject, "Test");
mail.emailSubject = subject
```

I replaced above code with this:

```
mail.emailSubject = (char*)"Test";
```

If anyone can explain, please feel free. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first block of code is allocating a stack char array and then assigns it to emailSubject which I don't know what type of object is. If it does not copy the stack memory but simply assigns it then when the function returns the stack memory will be deallocated and emailSubject will hold dirty memory.

When assigning "Test" the compiler will allocate "Test" as a static variable which is not deallocated after function returns.

Hope it helps.